# 19.04 bash : /usr/sbin/ip No such file or directory

Tags: bash, 19.04, paths

19.04 updated everyday

Today this happened :

```
ip r
bash: /usr/sbin/ip: No such file or directory
```

But then there's this :

```
 which ip
 /sbin/ip
```

This does not happen in a dash shell, but I don't want to use a dash shell.

I can fix with a symlink I suppose but that's a crude bandaid. What is going on? What is the proper fix? Other than switching to a dash shell, I mean.

*Updates*

```
type -a ip
ip is aliased to `/usr/sbin/ip -c'
ip is /sbin/ip
ip is /bin/ip
```

So the problem turned out to be that I had some years ago added that alias to my `bash_aliases`. This became obsolete.

**Thanks to steeldriver and Jeffrey**.

Comment: Please paste output from running the commands below under bash and again under dash.  (On Ubuntu 18.04 /sbin/ip is a symbolic link to /bin/ip)
ls -l /bin/ip /sbin/ip ;
alias ip ;
echo $PATH

Comment: @JeffreyRoss @steeldriver    Added info re symlinks to `ip`

Comment: So you need to track down and remove (or comment out) the "rogue" alias (check `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_aliases` etc.)

Comment: @steeldriver Yup. Thaks. I wanted the `-c` for colorized output. The `ip` command output is more dense than I find comfortable and the colorization helps. So I'm tossing about on what to do. I'll probably just correct the alias. And be back here in 2022 with the same question all over again.

Comment: Well there's no need to include the full path (so long as `ip` is somewhere on your `PATH`) so just use `alias ip='ip -c'` (look at how `ls` is aliased to `ls --color=auto` for reference)

Comment: @steeldriver Doh!

Comment: can run set -x and source ~/.bashrc will write to standard error a trace for each command after it expands the command and before it executes it.